# Display custom posts with shortcode

Tags: php, html, wordpress, shortcode

I've been searching this forum for help for 2 days now but I can't find a solution for what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a custom post type called "product" and inside each post in that post type there are two custom fields called produktnamn(a textfield with product name) and produktbild(a product image). that's it.

Now I need a shortcode to display a particular post in that post type by entering it's slug (which is the same as it's name).

like this:
[product name="myproduct"]

That will render the name and product image inside some HTML tags.

Please help!

My code so far:

```
//Product image
function cpt_content_func($atts){

    extract( shortcode_atts(['name' => null], $atts ) );

    $args = [
        'name' => $slug,
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'numberposts' => 1
    ];

    $posts = get_posts( $args );
    $post = $post[0];

    $title = $post->title;
    $id = $post->ID;

    get_post_meta('produktbild', $id);

    $content = $post[0]->post_title;
    return '<h3>'.$content.'</h3>';
}

add_shortcode('product','cpt_content_func');
```

Solved it. Here's the code!

```
function display_custom_post_type( $atts ){
// Handle the attributes
$atts = shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'cat' => ' '
    ), 
$atts, 'products_by_cat' );

// Set default values for the post
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'category' => $atts['cat']
);
// Get posts
$posts_array = get_posts( $args );

// Check if posts exist
if( !empty($posts_array) ){
    $string = '<div class="row">';
    foreach( $posts_array as $post ){
        $string .= '<div class="col-sm-3 text-center">';
        $string .= '<div class="product-container">';
        $string .= '<a href="' . get_field( "order_link", $post->ID ) . '">';
        $string .= '<img class="product-img" src="' . get_field( "produktbild", $post->ID ) . '">';
        $string .= '</a>';
        $string .= '</div>';
        $string .= '<p class="product-btn">' . get_field( "produktnamn", $post->ID ) . '</p>';
        $string .= '</div>';
    }
    $string .= '</div>';
} else {
    // Didn't find any posts.
}

// Return HTML
  return $string;
```

Comment: Any reason you can't just use WooCommerce?

Comment: My reason is that I want the website to be very light. I don't need the whole ecommerce package of functions for the website. We will only display some of our products (which is at maximum 20 products) on some pages. That's the only function I am after. I thought it would be alot easier to just create a shortcode to display for an example 4 of the products on a particular page. The whole ecommerce page for ordering products is external and outside of wordpress.

But feel free to discuss with me why I should use woocommerce still. I'm kind of new to all of this and I'm learning by doing.  :)

Comment: My advice would be to make a coding attempt at the problem. No one on SO is going to do it all for you from scratch. This is why you've been down voted. Actually my real advice is to use WooCommerce lol.

Comment: I understand that! I just thought it was unnecessary to show my code since it's a total mess probably haha. But I've added it to my first post!

I was told by a friend of mine (who don't want to help me all the way) that since I'm using advanced custom fields on this post type, I could just write this bit of code and customize it to my needs to fetch the two fields from each product and that was basically all I needed he said. But I don't know where to put it, or what to then delete from my existing code

    <?php $field = get_field($field_name, $post_id, $format_value); ?>

Answer (score -1):

I agree with James--I'd just use woocommerce.

But you first step has to be learning how to build a shortcode: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress-shortcodes-the-right-way--wp-17165

Once you've attempted creating your own shortcodes, if things still aren't working, that's the time to ask for help.

Comment: That tutorial is wrong and outdated and should **NOT** be used

Comment: I have already written a lot of shortcodes for the same website.